# how to make images same size in asp.net (slideshow using adrotator)

Tags: html, asp.net

I am trying to make an image slideshow in asp.net using adrotator but the issue I'm having is that all my images vary in size. how can i make these same size?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although you should provide more info for what exactly you're trying to achieve, I wrote the code below for you to show images with maximum width and height values. You can apply the same logic into the adrotator.

http://jsfiddle.net/Aka3k/

```
.ads li img {
    max-width:150px;
    max-height:150px;
    margin:10px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Just go the ad rotator properties and make the height and width the same.

All images now will be of the same size.

Comment: Please improve your answer with some proper formatting.